# SQL statement thinking non distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to retrieve all the rows from a table where all values of two columns in a row match other two values in another roe, eg I have  gps co-ords split in long and lat and I want to see do these match in any rows???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `GROUP BY` should work for you:

```
SELECT Col1,Col2
FROM YourTable T
GROUP BY Col1,Col2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Please post what you have tried going forward...

**--EDIT--**

If you're look at returning all rows that have the same lat/lon, then something like this would work:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE (lat,lon) IN (
      SELECT lat,lon
      FROM YourTable
      GROUP BY lat,lon
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9658/5

Comment: +1 . . . The alternative of doing a join is just unpleasant.

Comment: have tried something very similiar to this ie "select *" is only difference but it is only returning one instance of the matched values.

Comment: @user2096659 -- see this sample Fiddle -- if you can enter your test data which is not returning, I'll take a look: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71e85/3

Comment: @sgeddes he is looking for all the results I think, not just the lat long of rows which do match. So he either needs a join, a sub-select or a second look-up in his code. If he expects more than two matching records I would look to address in code.

Comment: @Matthew -- I updated my answer if that is what OP is looking for -- a little unclear from question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple conditions in a where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 
WHERE tbl1.lat = tbl2.lat AND tbl1.long = tbl2.long
```

For in the same table as you are asking you could try a self-join like this:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.ID from myTable as t1
INNER JOIN myTable as t2
WHERE t1.lat = t2.lat and t1.long = t2.long
```

Or using group to see how many and could get the actual records with a sub-select or a second query on the returned lat/longs:

```
SELECT t.lat, t.lng, count(*) from myTable as t
GROUP BY (t.lat, t.long)
HAVING Count(*) >=2
```

With the sub-select something like (may need to debug):

```
SELECT * from myTable as t1, 
(SELECT t.lat, t.lng from myTable as t
GROUP BY (t.lat, t.long)
HAVING Count(*) >=2) as t2
WHERE t2.lat = t1.lat and t2.long = t1.long
```

If there can be many records with identical lat/longs I would suggest pulling back the lat/long using the group by with having condition of 2 or more matches and then iterating over the table again to get all records that match for each pair in code.

Comment: I only have one table nad using something similar to your group by I get very close to what i want but it only returns one instance of the replicaed numbers ie i have the data entered so that it should return 2 rows but it only returns 1.